# VBA Excel Index out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a vba code for converting a CSV file to array and then analysing it in excel. The code was functioning very well but all of a sudden now I am getting the error 1004, it says  The method 'cells' for the object global failed. and is highlighting this line "Cells(j, 15).value = strRow1(0)" Below the code. Please if someone could help

```
Sub lithium()
Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
Dim PathInit As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim z As Long, filecount As Long
' Opening the txt file
Dim myTxt
myTxt = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")


Open myTxt For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
Close #1
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf) 

 Dim strRow1() As String
 Dim strRow2() As String
 Dim strRow3() As String
 Dim strRow4() As String
 Dim strRow5() As String
 Dim strRow6() As String
 Dim nCount As Integer

 nCount = 1
 Dim nRowLenth As Integer
 nRowLenth = UBound(strData) - LBound(strData) ' Length of the total data 
 array

 j = 3

 For i = 16 To nRowLenth


          strRow1() = Split(strData(i), ";")


           Cells(j, 15).value = strRow1(0)
           Cells(j, 16).value = strRow1(1)
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c0" Then Cells(j, 17).value = strRow1(2)
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c1" Then Cells(j, 18).value = strRow1(2)
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c4" Then Cells(j, 19).value = strRow1(2)
           Cells(j, 21).value = Left(Cells(j, 17).value, 2)
           Cells(j, 22).value = Left(Cells(j, 18).value, 2)
           Cells(j, 23).value = Right(Left(Cells(j, 18).value, 6), 2) & Right(Left(Cells(j, 18).value, 4), 2)
           Cells(j, 23).NumberFormat = "0000"
           Cells(j, 24).value = Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 2)

           Cells(j, 26).value = Right(Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 12), 2) & Right(Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 10), 2)
           Cells(j, 27).value = Right(Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 16), 2) & Right(Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 14), 2)
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c0" Then Cells(j, 1).value = Cells(j, 15).value Else _
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c1" Then Cells(j, 1).value = Cells(j, 15).value Else _
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c4" Then Cells(j, 1).value = Cells(j, 15).value Else _
           Cells(j, 1).value = ""
           If Cells(j, 21).value = "" Then Cells(j, 2).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 2).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 21).value)
           If Cells(j, 22).value = "" Then Cells(j, 3).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 3).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 22).value)
           If Cells(j, 24).value = "" Then Cells(j, 4).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 4).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 24).value) - 40
           Cells(j, 5).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 25).value) - 40
           If Cells(j, 23).value = "" Then Cells(j, 5).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 5).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 23).value) - 32768
           If Cells(j, 26).value = "" Then Cells(j, 6).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 6).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 26).value)
           If Cells(j, 27).value = "" Then Cells(j, 7).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 7).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 27).value)
           If Cells(j, 27).value = "" Then Cells(j, 8).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 8).value = Cells(j, 6).value - Cells(j, 7).value

 j = j + 1

Next

Call CopyPasteValue
Call timetransformation


End Sub
```

Also on the call function which I am using above is not functioning . When the same small function code is run separately but it does not work with the main code. Below the call function codes

```
SubCopyPasteValue()
Sheets("DataBase_1").Range("A1:H500").Copy
Sheets("DataBase").Range("A4").PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets ("DataBase").Columns("A").SpecialCells(x1CellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Sheets("DataBase").Columns("A").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub timetransformation()

Dim l As Long
Dim LR As Long
k = 2
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For l = 2 To LR

Range("I" & k).value = Val(Left(Right(Range("A" & l).value, 12), 2)) + Val(Right(Left(Right(Range("A" & l).value, 12), 5), 2)) / 60 + Val(Right(Right(Range("A" & l).value, 12), 6)) / 3600

k = k + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I can't really say what's the problem here. First try to be explicit in your `Cells` call and reference it to the correct sheet. A simple `With` clause will do. Then try to check if your `Open` call really retrieves and returns data. You can also be explicit in `Option Base = 0`. Try these first and see what happens.

Comment: Hi your comment looks little complicated I tried little changes with whatever I understood but I am not able to get the solution

Comment: @Santhosh He meant to reference better your `Cells`, like: `Dim ws As Worksheet` `Set ws = Thisworkbook.Sheets("The name of your sheet")` `With ws` `.Cells(j, 15) ...` `End WIth`.

Comment: Hi Rafael I gave the reference to the cells but the cells do not copy to the worksheet I wanted it to but instead the active worksheet. Is there a solution for this